# How do i get some command files to load?

Tags: typescript, discord.js

So, im trying to figure out why my discord bot isnt loading new commands. I created some new commands, in TypeScript. Now, one thing to note is i did rewrite the bot from javascript to typescript, for a web panel, though i may end up switching it back to JavaScript.

Here's the issue though. The existing commands from before the rewrite have worked fine and they still do, but new commands wont load...here is my command handler:

```
// src/commandHandler.ts

import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { Client, CommandInteraction } from 'discord.js';
import { Command } from '../../utils/commandTypes';

// Define a custom type that extends the Client type to include the 'commands' property
declare module 'discord.js' {
    interface Client {
        commands: Map<string, Command>;
    }
}

export const registerCommands = async (client: Client) => {
    client.commands = new Map();

    // Construct the absolute path to the 'cmds' directory
    const cmdsDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'cmds');

    const commandCategories = fs.readdirSync(cmdsDirectory);

    for (const category of commandCategories) {
        const categoryPath = path.join(cmdsDirectory, category);
        const commandFiles = fs
            .readdirSync(categoryPath)
            .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.ts'));

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            try {
              const modulePath = path.join(categoryPath, file);
              const cacheDeleted = delete require.cache[require.resolve(modulePath)];
          
              if (!cacheDeleted) {
                  console.error(`Failed to delete cache for ${modulePath}`);
                  continue; // Skip to the next module if cache deletion fails
              }
          
              console.log(`Cache Deleted for ${modulePath}`);
          
              const commandModule = await import(modulePath);
              const command = commandModule.default;
              client.commands.set(command.name, command);
          
              if (command && command.name) {

              } else {
                  console.error('Invalid command:', command);
              }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error loading command:', error);
            }
        
        }
    }
};

export const handleCommands = async (
    client: Client,
    interaction: CommandInteraction
) => {
    // if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);
    console.log(command);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.run(client, interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error executing command '${commandName}':`, error);
    }
};
```

is there a reason why its not loading the new commands? There is no error, and it does console.log the new commands info, just wont add them to the Application Command Menu

Comment: Are you trying to `await import()` the typescript files directly (ie without compiling them to javascript)? I don't think that's gonna work ...

Comment: in the past, it has worked. Should i just compile them?

Comment: In the past you had javascript files, so this worked, because node "understands" javascript. But it does not "understand" typescript. You are compiling the rest of your application before you run it, don't you?

Comment: Another possibility is, that you are indeed compiling your command modules already, and the directory you are loading them from just doesn't contain any files that meet `.filter((file) => file.endsWith('.ts'));` Because if it would try to load a module it can't parse, there should be an error. And as you say there is no error, it might be because it doesn't find any files to load

Comment: i have compiled the application. its just that none of the new commands from before the rewrite are loading...just the existing ones

Comment: Either attach a debugger and step through your module-loading code or add some debug output which tells you which files it actually tries to load ...

Comment: I assume you are compiling your code before you running it (no use of ts-node). Compiling the code will result in .js files and your handler is looking for .ts files. So he won't be able to find any of them as there are only .js files. The `.filter((file) => file.endsWith('.ts'));` should still filter for .js files.